# Probability with two different results

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are three universities: $U_1$, $U_2$, and $U_3$. $U1$ has three departments, $U_2$ has four departments, and $U_3$ has six departments. A tour is available that allows visitors to tour all the universities, with each having at least one department. Additionally, visitors can select 2 departments from any university to add to their tour. The visitor must choose a total of five departments while adhering to the condition of selecting at least one department from each university. The question is: What is the probability of the visitor touring all departments of $U_1$?

I've computed all the potential tour scenarios that the visitor can undertake. For instance, the scenario where the visitor visits 3 departments in $U_1$, 1 department in $U_2$, and 1 department in $U_3$ can be calculated as $(3 \cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 4 \cdot 6) \cdot 3!$. By performing similar computations for other cases and summing them, the probability can be determined.

However, I have a query regarding what happens if we consider only the selection of departments without accounting for the order. In this context, for the desired outcome, there are ${3\choose 3} \cdot {4\choose 1} \cdot {6\choose 1}$ ways to achieve it. Once again, by carrying out all the computations, we can calculate the various probabilities. Yet, the probabilities obtained in this approach differ. Why does this difference occur? Am I making an error by not considering the order? My intuition says that doesn't matters what approach I use, so I think that I'm doing something wrong in the second case.

Any hint is apreciated, and sorry about my english.

Comment: If you're touring five departments, and $U_3$ has six, there's zero probability of touring them all.

Comment: Sorry, is in $U_1$. I edited the question

Comment: Where did $(3\cdot 2\cdot 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 6)\cdot 3!$ come from?

Comment: For $U_1$ you have $3\cdot2\cdot1$ ways to visit de departments (if you visit all of them) and in the other universities you only have 4 and 6 options. The 3! is the way you can visit the universities.

Comment: If order matters, there are $3!$ ways to visit the departments at $U_1$ (in some order), $4$ ways to choose one of the $U_2$ departments, $6$ ways to choose one of the $U_3$ departments, and $3!$ ways to visit universities. But what about vising department $A$ at $U_1$, then department $A$ at $U_2$, then department $A$ at $U_3$, then departments $B$ and $C$ at $U_1$ again. Your method doesn't count this tour. Is this allowed?

Comment: You counted two different values. One in which order matters and one in which it doesn't. To go from there to probabilities, you need to divide by the total number of outcomes (assuming each outcome is equally likely). The total number of outcomes will be different between the two cases (order matters vs. order doesn't matter). Calculate the ratios and see if the difference disappears.

Comment: You go to the deparments in $U_1$ just once, so is not allowed to go to one university and then to go again.  Of course that if you count with the two approachs you get different results, but the ratios are also different. Why is that?

Comment: What are the ratios?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148060/discussion-between-jose-joaquin-carvajal-ramirez-and-bangs).